# Android: Importing Existing Code to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350484/android-eclipse-import-existing-code) is a duplicate name for the question but unfortunately doesn't serve.

I'm trying to import a [project](http://wissamfawaz.com/COALectures/16thSet.zip) called *MakeToastApp*. When importing, three different types of files are imported. Sometimes, only one, but it misses the *src* folder and the R.java files which carries the resource variables.

[image: output]

**NOTE** that not checking or checking is just for testing. I have tried all kind of imports but the project won't run without the src and resources. I'm new to this, read all of similar posts and need to get this running..Thanks.

Comment: Restart your environment once, check if in your working directory you actually have all the resources available.

Comment: it is importing the three projects at once, they should come together, not separated. It imports one folder by chance, no clue why the inconsistency

Comment: Try doing that one by one, also check your working directory

Comment: @ Atieh, I things your folder contains three sub folders, So it is showing total three imports.

Comment: @AstralProjection did that, src folder inside the main folder is empty and there is no R.java file at all.

Comment: If you check that through the file browser (Explorer) are the files you intend to be there present on the Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you import do following thing.
Delete everything except src, res folders, Manifest.xml file.
try this..

Comment: didn't work, res and Manifest are both in the src folder

Comment: How come.. It should not be in same folder. src, res should be different folders. And manifest as well

Comment: I have provided a link to the project, please check it out if you don't mind

Comment: Three files are there. Which one is correct(December...)

Comment: No I'm working on MakeToastProject only

Comment: Ok.. i got your problem...

Comment: please wait.. i am working on it..

Comment: Hey i have modified your project.. How can i send back to you.It s a zip file

Comment: my email: atiyaleb@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent code.. check it once. Now import that project. Your problem will solve

Comment: all is good, but the R.java is not being generated

Comment: In eclipse.. Project >> clean.. It automatically resolve your problem

Comment: not working, these projects are cursed

Comment: wait.. i ll give another solution

Comment: Hey all these are simple problems.. In the following link you will get detailed explanation. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

Comment: first of all, thanks for your time and support. Second, I generated the R.java following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583118/google-maps-api-v2-class-not-found/16583424#16583424 
Again, thanks and happy new year :)

Comment: mkyong tutorials best for beginners. I think it is best for you to practice his examples. Even i learned from this web site only..

Comment: Happy New Year... :)  Happy learning.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are facing this problem. But you can try another thing instead. Create an emptry project then copy the contents to your project manually

Comment: not working. I need the generated files by java..I have provided a link to the project, do you mind if you try it on your eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace,
- Then  Select root directory: /path/to/project Projects->Select All
- UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to
  working sets"
- Finish

If the problem is still exist then sure you have problem with your project. Means it is not a complete project or runnable project.

Comment: No projects are found to import. But if I import an Existing Android, it finds it. Please don't provide existing answers as I went through them all. Instead, you can find the link to the project and try importing it. Thanks.